# Number of possible sequences with i before j within all possible even permutation.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups

Given a sequence $\vec{\sigma}$ of length $L$ and two given elements $i$ and $j$ with $i$ before $j$. We want to look at all possible even permutation of $\vec{\sigma}$ and see how many of them has $i$ stays before $j$.

I have a feeling that we can solve this by looking at the even permutation group and the right coset of the subgroup {1, (i j)}, but cannot figure out the details.

Comment: **HINT:** Suppose we have a list of ordered elements $\{1,...,n\}$. Given a fixed index $i$, there are $(n-1)!$ ways to arrange this list that maintain the position of $i$. There $n-i$ spots to the right of the fixed index and $i-1$ spots to the left, which we are not allowed to put the other item in. Perhaps add this up across every $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ and you'll get the total number of permutations. But, deciding how many are even and how many are odd is a problem I won't be able to help you on (my group theory teacher was very bad).